# React Router: Navigate back to Search results

Tags: reactjs, react-router

### I have dynamic routes based on search results. How do I go back and see my previously rendered search results & search term in input field versus and empty `Search` page?

#### I've started looking into useHistory/useLocation hooks, but I'm lost.

#### 1. Search page

```js
export default function Search() {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [noResults, setNoResults] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key={API_KEY}&query=${searchValue}`
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    const results = data.results;

    if (results.length === 0) setNoResults(true);

    setData(results);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetchData();
    // setSearchValue("");
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          placeholder="Search by title, character, or genre"
          className="input"
          value={searchValue}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setSearchValue(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </form>

      <div className="page">
        <h1 className="pageTitle">Explore</h1>

        {isLoading ? (
          <h1>Loading...</h1>
        ) : (
          <div className="results">
            {!noResults ? (
              data.map((movie) => (
                <Result
                  poster_path={movie.poster_path}
                  alt={movie.title}
                  key={movie.id}
                  id={movie.id}
                  title={movie.title}
                  overview={movie.overview}
                  release_date={movie.release_date}
                  genre_ids={movie.genre_ids}
                />
              ))
            ) : (
              <div>
                <h1 className="noResults">
                  No results found for <em>"{searchValue}"</em>
                </h1>
                <h1>Please try again.</h1>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### 2. Renders `Result` components

```js
export default function Result(props) {
  const { poster_path: poster, alt, id } = props;

  return (
    <div className="result">
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: `/results/${id}`,
          state: { ...props },
        }}
      >
        <img
          src={
            poster
              ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${poster}`
              : "https://www.genius100visions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/placeholder-vertical.jpg"
          }
          alt={alt}
        />
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### 3. Clicking a result brings you to a dynamic page for that result.

```js
export default function ResultPage(props) {
  const [genreNames, setGenreNames] = useState([]);

  const {
    poster_path: poster,
    overview,
    title,
    alt,
    release_date,
    genre_ids: genres,
  } = props.location.state;

  const date = release_date.substr(0, release_date.indexOf("-"));

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchGenres = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(
        "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key={API_KEY}"
      );
      const data = await res.json();
      const apiGenres = data.genres;

      const filtered = [];

      apiGenres.map((res) => {
        if (genres.includes(res.id)) {
          filtered.push(res.name);
        }
        return filtered;
      });

      setGenreNames(filtered);
    };

    fetchGenres();
  }, [genres]);

  return (
    <div className="resultPage">
      <img
        className="posterBackground"
        src={
          poster
            ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${poster}`
            : "https://www.genius100visions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/placeholder-vertical.jpg"
        }
        alt={alt}
      />
      <div className="resultBackground">
        <div className="resultInfo">
          <h1> {title} </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### 4. How do I go back and see my last search results?

##### I'm not sure how to implement useHistory/useLocation with dynamic routes. The stuff I find online mentions building a button to click and go to last page, but I don't have a button that has to be clicked. What is someone just swipes back on their trackpad?

Comment: Are you wanting to persist the `searchValue` and/or `data` state of the `Search` component such that when a user navigates back to the page it's rendered on it can be repopulated?

Comment: yes both. so it’s a Disney+ clone. the way they do it is after search renders a bunch of responses, you click a movie to see the movie page, if you navigate back you’ll see all those same search results still there and the searchValue in the input. it goes immediately back to the state the page was before clicking.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this would be to persist the local component state to `localStorage` upon updates, and when the component mounts read out from `localStorage` to populate/repopulate state.

Use an `useEffect` hook to persist the `data` and `searchValue` to localStorage, when either updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('searchValue', JSON.stringify(searchValue));
}, [searchValue]);

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('searchData', JSON.stringify(data));
}, [data]);
```

Use an initializer function to initialize state when mounting.

```
const initializeSearchValue = () => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('searchValue')) ?? '';
};

const initializeSearchData = () => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('searchData')) ?? [];
};

const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(initializeSearchValue());
const [data, setData] = useState(initializeSearchData());
```